# Do I set my zend baseUrl manually?

Tags: zend-framework

I understand that baseUrls are mostly automatically set in zend projects, and they come in handy when running an app from a subfolder, But I'm running my app from the root `public` folder, with server-name `myzend.loc`.

So when I do an `echo $this->baseUrl()` or `var_dump($this->baseUrl())`, I get an empty string `''`. Is this normal and a result of not running the app from a subfolder? or do I set baseUrl manually; eg `$request->getHelper('baseUrl')->setBaseUrl($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is that on my ZF1 apps serving sites at the root of a virtual web host, I also get an empty string for:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl()
```

As @TimFountain notes, on its own, that doesn't return a true URL, complete with `http` or `https` protocol prefix. So, it can be interpreted more as a file-path than as a URL. But it's more of a *relative* file path: the path relative to the docroot.

And, of course, if you set the `baseUrl` - perhaps as a real URL complete with protocol prefix - then all interpretations are off: it merely returns whatever you set.

It is also worth noting two things about the `baseUrl()` view-helper implemented in `Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl`:

1. It uses the front-controller `getBaseUrl()` method above.
2. It takes an argument!

For (2), in my experience, many people use the `baseUrl()` view-helper as follows (in a view-script, say):

```
<?php echo $this->baseUrl() . '/assets/css/styles.css'; ?>
```

But I find it more concise to write:

```
<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/assets/css/styles.css'); ?>
```

To me, it's not just a matter of a few extra characters. It's more that the core of the app should know his own internal structure, but not his deployment details. Employing the `baseUrl()` view-helper this way implicitly acknowledges that there some deployment-aware mapping required to resolve an internal deployment-independent asset reference to its post-deployment counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->baseUrl()` is setted by the zend framework..you dont need to set..the reason why you are getting an empty baseurl is in your apache httpd.conf your Virtualhost documentroot is setted up to the project directory

`DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/yourproject"`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but this is my apache documentroot configuration: `DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myzend/public"`

Answer (score 2):

Despite the name, `baseUrl` returns an absolute path, not a URL. It returning an empty string would be what you'd expect from a normal ZF project that doesn't live in a sub-folder.