# Circular resource dependency error in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a bootstrap class which I want to use to set CSS variables:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initView()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

But trying to get the view resource fails at the `bootstrap('view')` stage. I get the error:

```
... Circular resource dependency detected' in C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php on line 662
...
```

Which is strange because this is the procedure that tutorials(and the zend documentation) use. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the method to something like `_initViewStuff()` and all will be fine.

The reason is that the bootstrap sequence in `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract` is as follows:

1. Your initial call to `$app->bootstrap()` in `public/index.php` runs through all `_initXxx()` methods (`@see Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract::getClassResourceNames()`) and calls `$this->bootstrap('xxx')` for each `Xxx` it finds. It will then do a similar thing for all the plugin resources defined by `resources.*` keys in `application.ini` (though yours never gets that far, as described below).
2. The call to `bootstrap('view')` internally stores a flag that he has started the process to bootstrap a resource called `view`.
3. He does a similar thing as (1), looking for a matching `_initXxx()` method. He find it and attempts to execute `$this->_initView()`
4. He notices the flag he set, indicating that he's gonna hit an infinite loop, so he bails out with circular dependency exception.

Typically, for each resource `xxx`, you bootstrap it using one (but not both, as you have discovered) of the following approaches:

1. Define an `_initXxx()` method.
2. Creating a plugin resource class named something like `My_Application_Resource_Xxx` (you inform that system that `My_Application_Resource_` is a namespace prefix for plugin resources using `pluginPaths.My_Application_Resource = /path/to/dir/containing/plugin` in `application/configs/application.ini`)

Comment: Yeah, you beat me to it. Serves me right for being so verbose. ;-)

Comment: thanks. Works perfectly. + @b.b3rn4rd. Could you guys help with some input on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132691/do-i-set-my-zend-baseurl-manually). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cant use this method name in your bootstrap class '_initView' because there is corresponding `Zend_Application_Resource_View`, just rename your bootstrap method name

Comment: There's no problem having an init method that matches the name of a built-in resource class, you just can't call `$this->bootstrap('foo')` where 'foo' matches the name of the method you're in, that's what causes the circular dependency.

Comment: Hi @TimFountain I've just got chance to check this, thank you for clarifying.